# VS Code Run Python through custom command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sublimetext

I want to run python code "foo.py" from within VS Code editor, but I DO NOT want to run it using the standard python.exe.  I actually run my python scripts by passing them to another python script called PythonRun.py as follows:

```
PythonRun.py foo.py
```

PythonRun.py will do some pre-run functionality and then pass foo.py on to pythonw.exe.  All output from foo.py will still be directed to stdout.

Currently, I am using Sublime Text and all I had to do to make this work was to create the following "pythonw.sublime-build" file inside my sublime packages/user folder:

```
{
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "cmd": ["PythonRun.py","$file"],   
    "file_regex": "File \"(.*)\", line (.*)"
}
```

While editing foo.py inside sublime, I can just press F7 to execute it through PythonRun.py and the output from foo.py appears correctly in the sublime log window.

How can the same functionality be achieved with VS Code?

Edit:
I tried creating a task with tasks.json, and I think it did execute my python script, but the output did not appear in the terminal or output window.  This doesn't seem to work as elegantly as sublime.  Also, a hotkey to execute would be nice.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "alan",
            "command": "c:\\Python37\\pythonw.exe",
            "args": ["app.py"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: have a look at tasks, launch is for starting a debugger

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks, I tried using tasks.json, and I think it worked, but the output did not redirect to the terminal or output window.  See above... I will include my tasks.json

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior